# Shading of round objects after 'model.setThemingColor(dbId, color, true)'

Tags: three.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have some round elements in a model. When trying to colorize those with `model.setThemingColor(dbId, color, true);` then shading of the elements becomes fairly bad and the object hard to understand.
[image: Objects with standard color]
[image: Objects after setThemingColor]

My question for a fix is then 2 different questions:

- Is it possible to use the normal shading of objects on top of the `model.setThemingColor(dbId, color, true);` to still get shadows etc.?
- Is it possible to set a tolerance for when edges should be drawn between faces? I assume this is based on som angle tolerance to avoid having too many edges in the model.

I have already tried using both loading option `isAEC: true` and `viewer.setDisplayEdges(true)` without luck.

I appreciate any advice that might push me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I'd believe **setThemingColor** goes with customized mesh setting which ignores the effect of outline. I think **setMaterial** can  be of use. Actually, it is often used to define custom textures or transparency.

I'd think the code below could be a workaround, but with my test, it does not work with some models. When it works, the effect is like the attached image. I am checking with team and will update the answer accordingly.

```
//select an object
var sel = NOP_VIEWER.getSelection()
console.log('sel Id:'+sel[0])  
var tree = NOP_VIEWER.model.getInstanceTree()
tree.enumNodeFragments(sel[0], (fragId) =>{ 
console.log('fragId:'+fragId) 

var updatedM = null
var cloneM_name = 'model:'+ NOP_VIEWER.model.id.toString() + '|frag:' + fragId.toString();
console.log('cloneM_name:'+ cloneM_name) 

if(cloneM_name in NOP_VIEWER.impl.matman()._materials)
{  
    updatedM = NOP_VIEWER.impl.matman()._materials[cloneM_name]
    updatedM.color = new THREE.Color(1,1,0) //my color  
    updatedM.needsUpdate = true; 
}else{
     console.log('add new material:'+ cloneM_name) 
     updatedM = NOP_VIEWER.model.getFragmentList().getMaterial(fragId).clone(); 
     updatedM.color = new THREE.Color(1,1,0) //my color   
     updatedM.needsUpdate = true;
     //add new material for this fragment
     NOP_VIEWER.impl.matman().addMaterial(cloneM_name,updatedM,true) 
}  
NOP_VIEWER.model.getFragmentList().setMaterial(fragId,updatedM) 
NOP_VIEWER.impl.invalidate(true,true,false)
 })
```

[image]